# Use one of two runners

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have two self-hosted runners, and I would like to use one of them for running E2E tests depending on their availability:

- If runner-1 is available, the job is executed on it.
- If runner-1 is busy, the job is run on runner-2.

How can I achieve this?
I tried to set it up this way, but GitHub keeps waiting indefinitely for an available runner:

> Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...

```yaml
  e2e-tests:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, actions-runner-1, actions-runner-2]
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think this is possible.  I think the intention is that runners of the same type are supposed to be completely interchangeable and so it's not intended to prefer a specific machine and fall back to another.